# How to interactively execute shell commands

Tags: rust

I have been looking into executing shell commands with `std::process::Command`. I have a problem when these commands use arguments. What I would like to do is to have a loop and in each iteration ask for an input and execute that string (no matter what) as it is as a shell command, capture its output and then jump on to the next iteration.

I have tried by splitting the string with `variable.split_whitespaces()` but this doesn't seem to work.

As a refactor, I would like the equivalent in rust to this python code

```py
import os

while True:
    try:
        command = input(">> ")
        os.system(command)
    except:
        print("There was an error")
```

Comment: Have you tried [`Command::args`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.args)?

Comment: One way to do this is to launch a shell as a command and then write new commands into the stdin buffer and take out the results from stdout. Maybe take a look at the 
subprocess crate: https://lib.rs/crates/subprocess  which makes this easier

Comment: What have you tried? What it your code?

Comment: I would just like an easy way of doing this like in python

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the input as a shell command, you have to give the command to a shell. The system-standard shell is usually available at `/bin/sh` and `-c` is how you execute a command from an argument.  That would look roughly like this in Rust:

```
let output = std::process::Command::new("/bin/sh")
    .args(["-c", the_user_input])
    .output()?;
```